# what's the correct way to define a function with returned type the same as its first parameter

Tags: typescript

What I want is simple, I want a function return a type the same as its parameter. I've tried the below code but it's wrong.

```
type IF = <T>(name: T) => T

let f: IF = (name: string) => {
    return name + ''
}
```

However, below code works but it's not my wanted

```
type IF = <T>(name: T) => T

let f: IF = (name) => {
    return name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've misplaced `<T>`
The code below works

```
type IF<T> = (name: T) => T

let f: IF<string> = (name: string) => {
    return name + ''
}
```